# count of the number of times that one element follows another one matlab

Tags: matlab, count, sparse-matrix

I have a vector containing a stream of positive real int.

```
A = [1 2 1 1 3 2 ];
```

I would like to create a sparse matrix `WW` (WxW, W is the number if distinct elements of A) where `W(i,j)` contains the count of the number of times that element `i` of A follows element `j` of A in the stream.

```
WW = 
   (1,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (1,3)        0
   (2,1)        1
   (2,2)        0
   (2,3)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (3,2)        0
   (3,3)        0
```

Comment: can you post the output of the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect job for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray([A(2:end).' A(1:end-1).'], 1, [], @sum, [], true);
```

Or you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) directly:

```
result = sparse(A(2:end), A(1:end-1), 1);
```

In your example, either of the above gives

```
result =
   (1,1)        1
   (2,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (2,3)        1
```